# Difference between static members of Java and static members of C++

Tags: java, c++, class, static

I have studied C++ and now I'm studying Java. In C++ we can use static members in non-static/instance member functions. But while studying Java I found this :

[image]

I wrote a program to check if " the non-static function can access static member or not". And there was no problem in the program below :

```
public class Animal
{
    static int CountOfAnimal;
    public Animal()
    {
        CountOfAnimal++;
    }
    public int showCount()
    {
        CountOfAnimal++;
        return CountOfAnimal;
    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        new Animal();
        new Animal();
        Animal C = new Animal();
        System.out.println("Total animals are : " + C.showCount());
    }
}
```

So, can I say that in Java also the non-static/instance member functions can access static members of same class?

Also, I want to know if there is any difference between static members(methods and variables) in Java and C++ other than the way of calling the members?

One difference I know is in the way of calling the static members in C++ and calling static members in Java. Any other?

Comment: `can I say that in Java also the non-static/instance member functions can access static members of same class?` Yes you can. The passage you cite doesn't in any way contradict that, so it's not clear why you've ever doubted this proposition to begin with.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : thanks, so there is no other difference between static members of java and c++(accept the way of calling)?

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding of the quoted text. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Note that it doesn't say that a non-static method can't access a static class member, which is what your code does. It says that a static method cannot access a non-static class member (or method). It's the other way around.

This is also true with C++ for exactly the same, underlying, fundamental reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sam Varshavchik had mentioned "**static method cannot access a non-static class member**".

For your other question, what's *the difference between static in C++ and Java*.

> C++ supports static Local Variables. Java Doesn't.

Ex: **Perfectly Valid in C++, but Error in Java.**

```
static int fun()  {
     static int abc = 1;
   }
```

> Java Supports Static Blocks/Static Classes. C++ Doesn't

Ex:

```
static
{
   System.out.println("Static block called");
}

class TestOuter1{  
  static int data=30;  
  static class Inner{  
   void msg(){System.out.println("data is "+data);}  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
  TestOuter1.Inner obj=new TestOuter1.Inner();  
  obj.msg();  
  }  
}
```

Comment: All nested classes in C++ are equivalent to static inner classes in Java. C++11 lambdas are sort of equivalent to non-static inner classes in Java, in the manner they capture local variables.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, I wasn't aware of C++ Lambdas. But static inner classes in java is quite different from C++ inner classes. AFAIK, C++ Inner classes can access the private variables of Outer classes, however this is not supported in Java as only static variables are allowed to be accessed.
So I would say Inner classes of C++ is Somewhat Similar to Inner classes of java rather than static classes of Java. Would you agree?

Comment: @Infinity, if this is answered. Can you accept the answer and close out the question?